# Anylogic PLE: Source with a poisson distributed arrival rate

Tags: distribution, poisson, anylogic

I'm using the Anylogic PLE Version 8.2.3.

A Source-object should generate agents with a poisson distribution.
The lambda observed in reality is `0.1215`.

My settings in the Source-object are:

- `"Arrivals defined by": "rate"`
- `"Arrival rate": poisson(0.1215)`

The problem:

The Source doesn't generate agents with this lambda. The Source only creates agents with a lambda of about `0.32`.

However: If I assign the expression `poisson(0.1215)` to a variable or a parameter (e. g. `Paramater1 = poisson(0.1215)`), the probability distribution is correct.

Can someone help?

Comment: removed fluff, fixed grammar, improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

When you chose arrivals defined by rate, you already have a poisson distribution, so instead of poisson(0.1215) you should just write 0.1215...